# Dynamic memory management i386 vs amd64

Tags: memory, exploit-development

I've spotted some differences in the behavior of the GNU/Linux dynamic memory allocator in i386 vs amd64. While it's possible that I'm misunderstanding something ( in this case let me know ), I don't understand why these differences are present and before digging inside the code I want to know if anybody has already investigated this.

Let's take this program ( test.c ) as example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(){

     unsigned int *a = malloc(100);  //(1)
     memcpy(a,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",18);
     free(a); //(2)
     unsigned int *b = malloc(10); //(3)
     memcpy(b,"BBBBBB",6);
     return 0;
    }
```

After the malloc in (1) we have in both cases that the space is taken directly from the top chunk, and this is as expected:

[image]

However after the free in (2) the first difference can be noted:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot in the ELF-64 bits the chunk that has been freed is not updated with the new size, but the size is still 0x71 and the first QWORD is nullified. In the ELF-32 bits, as I expected, the freed chunk is instead merged with the Top Chunk and the size is updated to 0x20f99 + 0x68 = 0x21001.

Later when the second malloc in (3) is executed, in the x64 case the new chunk is allocated right after the previously chunk by shrinking the top chunk, while in the i386 case the previously freed chunk is reused.

These are only two of the differences that I have noticed, and I think that there are many others...

So, is there somewhere a document/research/white-paper that describes these differences?

I am using the **libc-2.23.so** on an Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance for any insight about this.

Comment: I'd recommend asking in [libc-help](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/). Probably the pointer size difference make for the difference in the chunks that get created.

Comment: Yes, the pointer size influences for example the size of the chunk's header ( in the ELF-64 it is of 2 DWORD ). The strange behavior is more in the work of the free in (2) and the next malloc in (3). I thought that the behavior would remain the same since the code is the same, but this differences destroy my certainties. I will consider to ask in libc-help if anybody here can't help me. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: in the glibc IRC they suggest me to investigate the malloc parameters, so I've investigated with mallinfo, malloc_stats and malloc_info but I've spotted no particular difference. I've also investigated with strace, but the traces seems equivalent.